# Android - How can i install my app to sd card

Tags: android, database

I created my android app. I installed my telephone. But it was saved my telephone. I want to save APP and DATABASE to my sd card. Because when people formatted telephone, app and db datas will not delete

Answer (score 2):

1. In your manifest

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="YOUR_PACKAGE"
       android:installLocation="internalOnly"
   ```

   `android:installLocation` can be changed to `preferExternal` for preference to external storage. But this doesn't gurantee the application will be install on external storage, as from the Android references

   > The application prefers to be installed on the external storage (SD
   >   card). There is no guarantee that the system will honor this request.
   >   The application might be installed on internal storage if the external
   >   media is unavailable or full. Once installed, the user can move the
   >   application to either internal or external storage through the system
   >   settings.

   Read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) for more information about manifest elements(as refered by a respected user below)
2. If the app data is stored as `SharedPreference` it will be automatically cleared on device format, so you may opt to save your preferences to External Storage from the application using custom preference files.

   Read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for ways to store data on android.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html for more information